# How to use border-image on border-top only?

Tags: css, border-image

As per screenshot, how if the line become transparent when reach the center of wording part? can we use css gradient to achieve it?

[image]

```css
    h2.section-title {
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 .section-divider h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
 }
 .section-divider {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  
  margin-top: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="section-divider">
     <h2 class="text-center section-title" lang="en">Highlights</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/XWVxk/8/ ?

Comment: @Sachin I am very much sure, this is what conmen wanted. It would be really great to post it as a separate answer and explained what you did in it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not my answer. I'm just adding code snippet of solution given by @Sachin in comment section of question.

```css
h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: red;
}
h1:before {
    margin-left: -50%;
    text-align: right;
}
.color {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is my Title</h1>
<h1>Another Similar Title</h1>
<div class="color"><h1>Just Title</h1></div>
```